# ¿Podrían ayudarme a solucionar problema al crear proyecto en asp .net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, visual-studio-2017

Al crear un proyecto en asp net con MVC en visual studio 2017 me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: Al crear un proyecto en asp net con MVC me aparece este error]

Sin embargue dentro de la carpeta contenedora del proyecto se generan todos lo archivos correspondientes al proyecto; si intento abrir el proyecto desde la carpeta contenedora el error que me muestra es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado ya editar el archivo applicationHost.config con mi dirección ip así como borrar el archivo y abrir nuevamente el proyecto, sin embargo el error persiste.
Si alguien pudiera orientarme para dar solución a este problema les estaré muy agradecido.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba ejecutar Visual Studio como administrador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el problema se presenta cuando intentas crear una aplicación web nada más, es problema con el IIS.

Realiza lo que está en este enlace [describe los pasos para solucionar tu problema](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79fb4abd-dcca-4568-8e62-665af0a9d807/unspecified-error-exception-from-hresult-0x80004005-efail-has-occurred-while-creating-new-web?forum=vssetup)

Suerte.